# How to use javascript variable in script src

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using a ajax call which returns the json data, now a value from json should be added in script src tag

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    success: function(data,response){
         console.log("inside sucess");
         console.log(data);
        for(i=0;i<data.files.length;i++){
            if(window.location.href.indexOf(data.files[i].video_id)>=0){
                 id=JSON.parse(data.files[i].id);
            }
        }
    },
    failure: function(data,response) {
         console.log("Failed"); 
    }});
```

The script tag iam using is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.3playmedia.com/p/projects/18588/files/id/plugins/10960.js"></script>
```

Here instead i want to replace id in src with the id from ajax.

How to do it?

Comment: even if you change the id , will it make any difference since the script is already load with previous id ? this is something wierd

Comment: @yoYO : That is the challenge, the script src id should be dynamic, i want to make it dynamic. but how?

Comment: Since you've add jQuery tag, so I suggest you using `$.getScript()` method. See this reference https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

by the time the Ajax call finishes and your success callback is executed, it is highly likely that the script tag you wish to alter has been requested already.

Assuming what you want to do is dynamically decide which script to download based on the response from the AJAX call, you could create a script tag in the success callback, and inject it into the page. Something like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'my_dynamic_path.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Should probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<script id="scriptTag" type="text/javascript" src="//static.3playmedia.com/p/projects/18588/files/id/plugins/10960.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    success: function(data,response){
         console.log("inside sucess");
         console.log(data);
        for(i=0;i<data.files.length;i++){
            if(window.location.href.indexOf(data.files[i].video_id)>=0){
                 id=JSON.parse(data.files[i].id);
                 $("#scriptTag").attr('src','img///static.3playmedia.com/p/projects/18588/files/id/plugins/'+id+".js"); 
            }
        }
    },
    failure: function(data,response) {
         console.log("Failed"); 
    }});
```